# Python RocksDB Combine / Merge DBs

Tags: python, database, bigdata, rocksdb

I find myself in a situation where I have my rather large (100s of gbs) dataset split up in many 'chunks', where each chunk is rocksdb database with the exact same format of keys / values. I would need to make fast queries across the entire dataset, so it would make sense for me to combine these chunks into a single rocksdb database rather than make the same query on chunk 1, chunk 2, ... chunk n and combine the results, as combining would fully utilize the optimized rocksdb methods like `multi_get` ect. Here is a code example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
import rocksdb

chunk1 = rocksdb.DB('chunk1.db', rocksdb.Options(create_if_missing=True))
chunk2 = rocksdb.DB('chunk2.db', rocksdb.Options(create_if_missing=True))
chunk3 = rocksdb.DB('chunk3.db', rocksdb.Options(create_if_missing=True))

# Populate dbs here

chunk1.multi_get(keys)
# 1, 2, None, None, None, None
chunk2.multi_get(keys)
# None, None, 3, 4, None, None
chunk3.multi_get(keys)
# None, None, None, None, 5, 6

# I am looking for how to implement this combine method
full_set = combine(chunk1, chunk2, chunk3)

full_set.multi_get(keys)
# 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Is there a way to implement the `combine` method above without opening each database chunk and then  reading every line and writing it to combined database? The reason I don't want to just fully reread and recreate the combined database is that the chunks are populated dynamically onto my machine and can change every few days, so frequently waiting for a long combine operation would not be ideal. I have attempted the solution discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/499), however I was not able to get a combined database after running `repair`, as it would discard all the new `.sst` files and only keep the original set.

Alternatively, if anyone knows any other database similar to rocksdb that easily achieves this, I am also open to suggestions.